# Выбор домена

Tags: домен

Всем привет, хочу снять домен для портфолио, хочу посоветоваться... Хочу чтобы домен был связан с фамилией, но sklyar.ru и .com заняты, можете предложить хорошие альтернативы? прошу помочь, со стороны просто лучше видно)

Comment: Может [`.name`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name) ?

Comment: @mantigatos, а как его зарегистрировать?  он вроде свободен, но там написано типа домены предназначены для профессионалов различных областей деятельности. Как пройти проверку, или куда писать?)

Comment: Вряд-ли. Такой домен как-раз позиционируется для широкого использования. [Тут](http://www.makea.name/find-registrar/) пишут что всего три простых шага.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так побывал http://www.alsklyar.ru/ 
    На www.r01.ru 
        свободен ALSKLYAR.RU    ALSKLYAR.RU  whois.r01.ru 
        Свободен

```
     whois.registry.ripn.net    
    Свободен
```